# Importing a repository (branch) into Artifactory (cloud) using their API via curl

Tags: api, artifactory

I've not been having much luck importing a branch (`ext-snapshot-local`) exported from an on-prem artifactory server into a cloud artifactory repo (credentials are ok and can create dummy files ok) and I find the online API doco somewhat underdone.

JFrog have mentioned that '...if the path we specified for the export was "/Users/name", we specified the "path" part of the curl command to be "path=/Users/name/repositories/" as the export folder is named "repositories" by default.' (which is not 100% clear to me as they seem to be specifying the default...)

Anyway, I have tried:

```
curl -u $MY_UID:$MY_PWD -X POST "https://organisation.jfrog.io/organisation/api/import/repositories?path=/home/user/src/artifactory/repositories&verbose=1"
```

Only to receive

```
Starting Repositories Import of All repositories from /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

400 : Directory /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories does not exist.

500 : No directory for repository ext-release-local found at /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

500 : No directory for repository ext-snapshot-local found at /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

500 : No directory for repository libs-release-local found at /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

500 : No directory for repository libs-snapshot-local found at /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

500 : No directory for repository jcenter-cache found at /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories

500 : Error occurred during import: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
  at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
  at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
  at org.artifactory.repo.service.ImportJob.collectSubdirectoriesNames(ImportJob.java:237)
  at org.artifactory.repo.service.ImportJob.checkForUnusedSubdirectories(ImportJob.java:219)
  at org.artifactory.repo.service.ImportJob.onExecute(ImportJob.java:128)
  at org.artifactory.schedule.quartz.QuartzCommand.execute(QuartzCommand.java:48)
  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
  at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:30)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which is not the case as the repository (branch) is found in:

```
/home/user/src/artifactory/repositories/ext-snapshot-local
```

Comment: Same happens of I tack `/ext-snapshot-local` onto the end too.

Comment: Check the permissions on the path. Meaning that the user that runs Artifactory should have permissions on the path of the /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories/

Comment: User has adequate permissions (rw), they were the one that created the path and files (from zip of repo branch)

Comment: can you add the output of the following command:
"ls -al /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories"
screenshot will be for the best

Comment: ls -la /home/user/src/artifactory/repositories/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 user 4096 Mar 21 10:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 user 4096 Mar 19 16:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 user 4096 Mar 15 11:32 ext-snapshot-local
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 4096 Mar 15 11:32 ext-snapshot-local.artifactory-metadata